# Munich - how can I quickly figure out which station belongs to what ring?

Tags: public-transport, munich

I'm looking for a resource (web app,  phone app or whatever) where I can quickly check which S-bahn or U-bahn station belong to a particular Ring. I'm asking because here's what it looks like officially (can be found [here](http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/fileadmin/media/Dateien/3_Tickets_Preise/dokumente/TARIFPLAN_Gesamtnetz_2017_EnglischmitLegende.PDF)):

[image]

And that just does not make thing easier.

Comment: Note that rings are important only for week and month passes. Single- and multi-trip tickets go by zone, and the entire city is in the white zone (if you went by car, you'd see the "leaving Munich" sign between the last station connected to the white zone, and the next).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to [Pläne & Bahnhöfe / Bahnhofsinformation](https://www.mvv-muenchen.de/plaene-bahnhoefe/haltestellen/index.html), select the staion from the drop down menu. Scroll down to Tickets und Preise and you will see.

[image]

[image]

So the Goetheplatz is ring 1 and the white zone.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken.

Comment: link corrected (edit in peer review now)

Comment: Link broken again

Answer (score 7):

#### Update

Been living there for some time as a frequent traveler. I gotta check the rings all the time to have the right combination of tickets for the journey.

The most convenient way is to use [MVG Fahrinfo München](https://www.mvg.de/services/mobile-services/fahrinfo.html) app's journey planner on your mobile device.

[image: MVG Fahrinfo München]

#### Original

Even though this won't be answering your question directly, but I found out that [MVV Journey Planner](https://efa.mvv-muenchen.de/index.html) shows you that how many rings you need to travel to reach your destination; which comes very handy to purchase the best-value ticket.

[image]